# Why does SELECT 1/2 return 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

As the title says. I even tried `SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC, 1/2)` which also returned 0.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They're integers.

Try:

```
select 1.0/2.0;
```

Or:

```
select CONVERT(NUMERIC,1)/CONVERT(NUMERIC,2);
```

Answer (score 14):

First, you are executing the numbers as integers but second, you also have not defined the precision and scale of the [numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) datatype.

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(5, 2), 1.0/2.0)
```

or even

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(5, 2), 1/2.0)
```